# How big image storage volume is needed for multi docker Elastic Beanstalk environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ebs

As per [Amazon documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.container.console.html#docker-volumes)

> Elastic Beanstalk configures two Amazon EBS storage volumes for your
>   Docker environment's EC2 instances. In addition to the root volume, a
>   second 12GB volume named xvdcz is provisioned for image storage on
>   Docker environments.

Taking into account that the size of the images for running my environment does not exceed 2GB, can I cut the additional volume to that size?

And how can I measure how much storage is actually used?

Comment: That note sounds like it's just automatic. But in the end, its Elastic Beanstalk, so you can test it out in less than an hour.

Comment: I tested and reduced image storage volume to 4GB and it did work. But that's probably not proper engineer solution :(

Comment: Scientific method at least. :)